# Since a function is $f$, not $f(x)$, how do you denote $\int f(x,y)g(y)dy$?

Tags: functions, notation

It's usually stated that the correct symbol of a function should be $f$, because $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at the point $x$. I tend to follow this convention, but there are ocassions when this notation seem to be almost unsuitable.

For example, if there are several functions and variables:

$$\int _{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)g(y)dy$$

Is there any nice way to denote the integral?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're denoting it, $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)g(y) \, \mathrm dy$?

Comment: Without function terms, one can write $h=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\cdot,y) g(y) dy$. One can also write $h=x \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) g(y) dy$. Personally I think the insistence that function terms are mathematically incorrect is a bit silly, at least when talking among people who understand functions. (With algebra or precalculus students, I can understand.)

Comment: I would not worry about it. It's kind of pedantic to get caught up in this view once you continue in deeper and deeper math. After a while, it is more convienent to use the simplified notation that you have presented in the integral. of course the integrand could be replaced by $fg\operatorname{dy}$ with specifications to each of the functions. But why worry?

Comment: "It's kind of pedantic to get caught up in this view once you continue in deeper and deeper math." Funny, I would have said the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to the function
$$ x \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) g(y)\; dy$$

Comment: And maybe $A ∋ x \mapsto ∫_{-∞}^∞ f(x, y)g(y) dy$ if we want to stress the domain of the resulting function.